# save a tree as a key in a dictionary, Python 3.4

Tags: python, xml, dictionary, tree

I have hundreds of xml files. I have function to compare 2 xml tree and return true if they are identical. 
each xml tree have unique id number which is ignored in the comparison.

now I can iterate over all the xml files and compare them. but I want to save the trees in a data structure like dictionary. but python not allowing me to save tree as a key and its id as a value. 
is there a way to have a dictionary of tree as key? if not then what type of data structure could be used for this?

example: 
[image]

Note that Tree1 = Tree2 but != Tree3 (ignoring the id) So I want my dic or any data structure to be like:

```
dic = {Tree1:[I1.i1.p1.m1, I1.i1.p1.m2], Tree3: [I1.i1.p1.m3]}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a **text** example, and some actual code? In general, objects must be implement `__hash__` and `__eq__` to act as dictionary keys.

Comment: Not everything can be a dictionary key, please read http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm search for "restrictions" in page.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are HashMaps. That means the keys must be hashable, which usually implies that the object to be hashed is immutable (reason why lists are not valid keys, but tuples are).

What you need is a function that generates this hash for your objects. Generating a hash over a tree-like data structure is a non trivial problem. But, since you can already formulate equality you must have an idea about some of the features that make your data identifiable.

You can always build a hash over a feature vector. Features that could be used:

1. depth of the tree
2. number of children
3. hash over an already available serialisation

Answer (score 0):

Here a generic solution that allow to say if 2 xml trees are identical except for certains attributes.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml1 = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><Math mode="inline" tau="tex" xml:id="foo"><XMath>2x+3c</XMath></Math>'
xml2 = '<Math mode="inline" tau="tex" xml:id="bar"><XMath>2x+3c</XMath></Math>'

#see for more informations https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

def almost_equals(tree1, tree2, attributes_to_ignore):
    """ Return true or false depending on the fact that tree1 and tree2 are identical except for the attributes whose the tag is in attributes to ignore. """
    #remove attributes to ignore
    for attribute in attributes_to_ignore:
        try:
            tree1.attrib.__delitem__(attribute)
        except:
            pass    
        try:
            tree2.attrib.__delitem__(attribute)
        except:
            pass

    #compare nodes
    if tree1.tag != tree2.tag:
        print(tree1.tag,"!=",tree2.tag)
        return False

    if tree1.attrib != tree2.attrib:
        print(tree1.attrib,"!=",tree2.attrib)
        return False

    if tree1.text != tree2.text:
        print(tree1.text,"!=",tree2.text)
        return False

    subtrees1 = list(tree1)
    subtrees2 = list(tree2)

    if len(subtrees1) != len(subtrees2):
        return False

    result = True
    for i in range(len(subtrees1)):
        result = result and almost_equals(subtrees1[i], subtrees2[i], attributes_to_ignore)

    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    xmlTree1 = ET.fromstring(xml1)
    xmlTree2 = ET.fromstring(xml2)
    print("The 2 xml trees are identical ({0})".format(almost_equals(xmlTree1, xmlTree2, ["{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}id"])))
```

Hope it helps.
Arthur.

Edit : You can save XML as xml and parse them on demand, or svae the Element object generated by the built in python library.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that works, but one of the possible solutions could be converting the node to a str, for example if you have a `root` of the tree

```
dic = {}
dic[str(root)]= "I am a root"
```

I think it should work

(but if two nodes have the same structure then it may not work)

maybe adding some other features, like numbering the node